How to draw straight line with fixed width
I am using inkscape. I insert aruco svg files. Now I want to put reference lines so its easier to cut them up. How do I draw straight vertical and horizontal lines with fixed width?

Do you mean guides?  Click, drag and drop guides from the rulers.

A direct answer to your question is to select the stroke width in the appropriate palette, (Control-Shift-L), place your first point and hold down the control key while you locate the second point. In so doing, you are restricting the path to be horizontal or vertical.
An alternative is to use the guide line feature. Drag from the top ruler if you desire to have a horizontal line, from the left ruler for a vertical line. You can position more precisely the line by double clicking on it to present a dialog box for this purpose.
A convenient aspect of this feature is that you can hide the lines and re-display them as you like. You can also delete specific lines by selecting them (color change on click) and pressing the delete key or you can use the aforementioned double click and click the delete button in the dialog box.
As they are guide lines, they are not a fixed width, they are zero width. If you require printable lines, use the first paragraph method. Of course, you can use both methods combined. Place the guides where desired, then use the guides to create the strokes of desired width. Inkscape will snap to the lines and also to the intersections, if you have not deselected that feature.
